# Backbone - how to pass this.files on file input change event in backbone view

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, input, backbone-views

In normal html, I write like this:

```
<input id="input-upload-image" type="file" multiple onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
```

In Backbone, I write like this to get the same functionality:

```
events: { 'change #input-upload-image': 'handleFiles' }

handleFiles: function () {}
```

My question is how to pass `this.files` to `handleFiles` function in Backbone.

P.S.
I tried `$(e.currentTarget).val();` but it return just one file even if I choose more than one file.

Comment: ’handleFiles: function (e) {  e.currentTarget.files`

Comment: @MysterX , your solution work perfectly. Please write it as answer to accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access files of input with the event parameter of the `change` listener

`handleFiles: function (e) { console.dir(e.currentTarget.files)}`